# Why would tracert command in Windows timeout except for last hop?

Tags: windows-10, traceroute

On my Windows 10 system on company network any time I attempt to run a basic ***tracert*** command to an internal or external resource (e.g. google.com) each identified hop results in "Request timed out" except for the final hop to destination. What could be the reasons for this? I have checked firewalls and confirmed it is working for other systems on my subnet. It is not filtered on network ACLs either.

[tracert google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/078wC.png)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but one that should be addressed to your network team.

Comment: So what is the purpose of this site if folks are redirected to their local teams? Besides, I have already done so. These are systems in a business environment so unless there is another community that would be more appropriate than this I would disagree with your subjective assessment of "on-hold, off-topic". Categorically it would not belong in the other two.

Comment: The point of this site is to help the people that are in charge of **managing** the systems in question. We expect people to have the necessary permissions on the systems in question to obtain logs, configuration snippets, etc. In this case, you do not have that and as such are a **user** of the system, not the **administrator** of the system.

Comment: Not true. I have administrative rights

Comment: Well then edit your question to include firewall configs, switch configs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Routers can be configured to not respond with an ICMP message that traceroute depends on. Also, MPLS can do that because it is not routing, it is label switching.

When a router needs to create an ICMP message to send back to the source host, that is a low priority task that it may no get around to in time. Also, some router administrators don't want their busy routers to even need to spend cycles doing that, so they disable it altogether. It could also be that network administrators don't want to give away that information.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We have other systems that have no issue with the command. I have checked with our network team regarding ICMP config/block and it has been confirmed that it is allowed.

Comment: Apparently, you do not understand how that tool works. A hop is discovered by the receipt of an ICMP TTL exceeded message from the hop. The hop is not sending back the message, or not in time. This has to do with the hops (routers).

Comment: Actually I do understand how the tool works. So can you answer why it would not respond for my system and yet it would for another? That is the question.

Comment: It could be too busy to respond in time. You have not provided nearly enough information to do anything but speculate.

Comment: The network is not that busy.

Comment: You have not provided any evidence of that. My answer is good for what is included in the question.